# How to use TDictionary?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2009

By using Google I have found some nice snippets of example code for using TDictionary in Delphi, but have not been able to compile any of them.

I use Delphi 2009 Update 1,2,3,4.

When I write this:

```
var Dic: TDictionary<Integer,string>;
```

I get "Unknown idenitifier TDictionary<,>"

How to use them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you added Generics.Collections to your **uses** list?

Comment: I thought its for NET.Thanks!

Comment: Yeah.  Generics.Collections was designed specifically to be similar interface-wise to the .NET generic collections, but they don't quite work the same way.